# problema a pasar una variable en laravel (RESUELTO)

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un sistema al cual tengo que asignar los cambios dependiendo de un valor de la tabla no de su id, y cuando envio el valor de la variable me responde que mi funcion espera mas de un valor.

mi vista es asi

```
 <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead class="thead">
                            <tr>
                                <th>PartCode</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($factura as $depositogracca)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $depositogracca->id }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $depositogracca->guia }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $depositogracca->numeroFactura }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $depositogracca->producto }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $depositogracca->modelo }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary " href="{{ route('depositogracca.agregar',$depositogracca->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i> Agregar</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

mi ruta

```
Route::get('agregaradepositogracca',[App\Http\Controllers\DepositograccaController::class, 'agregaradepositogracca'])->name('depositogracca.agregar');
```

y mi controlador

```
public function agregaradepositogracca($id){
        
        return view('depositogracca.indexfactura')
        
        ;}
```

Comment: a la próxima podrías poner el error que te devuelve. Siempre es más fácil encontrar el error si lo ves.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes en que en la ruta no estás pasando el id que tiene que espera en el método que devuelve la vista.

Cambia:

```
Route::get('agregaradepositogracca',[App\Http\Controllers\DepositograccaController::class, 'agregaradepositogracca'])->name('depositogracca.agregar');
```

Por:

```
Route::get('agregaradepositogracca/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\DepositograccaController::class, 'agregaradepositogracca'])->name('depositogracca.agregar');
```

Puedes echar un ojo a las rutas con parametros requeridos [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#required-parameters).